# How can I replace a duplicate word in a specific condition using REGEXP_REPLACE?

Tags: regex, postgresql, duplicates, conditional-statements, regexp-replace

I basically need to replace a duplicate word in a certain condition, but the word appears a lot of times throughout the string. So how can I transform this:

```
') test test test'
```

Into this:

```
') test successful successful'
```

I tried using this and some other variants of it, but none worked:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(') test test', '!~*[)] test|test)', 'succesful','gi')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for normally requires a regex engine that supports variable-length lookbehind since only occurrences of `test` with at least one occurrence of `test` behind them are to be replaced.

To work around the lack of such a support in PostgreSQL, you can replace the first occurrence of `test` with a dummy text that is highly unlikely to ever occur in any given input, then proceed to replace the rest of the occurrences of `test` with `successful`, and finally replace the dummy text back to `test`:

```
SELECT replace(replace(regexp_replace(') test test test', ' test', '!!dummy!!'), ' test', ' successful'), '!!dummy!!', ' test')
```

Demo: https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/7d9cfe4